# O que é árvore geradora mínima?

Tags: algoritmo, grafo

Tenho um exercício para resolver e o professor me disse bastava eu utilizar este método para resolver.
O que é árvore geradora mínima e como posso usar isso na prática?

Comment: http://www.lcad.icmc.usp.br/~nonato/ED/Grafos/node81.html

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Uma **árvore geradora** em um grafo você já conhece, mesmo sem saber!

Pense nesse grafo aqui (que ficou feio, mas para algo automatizado até que tá ok :P)

[image: grafo]

**Uma árvore geradora é simplesmente um conjunto de arestas do grafo que gera uma árvore.**

**Toda árvore é um grafo conexo acíclico**. Mas é mais fácil imaginar o mesmo grafo com pelo menos uma aresta entrando e no máximo uma (ou seja, não necessariamente há uma) aresta saindo de cada vértice.

Por exemplo, uma árvore geradora no grafo acima pode ser esta:

[image: st]

Os dois algoritmos clássicos em grafos, a **busca em profundidade** e a **busca em largura**, induzem árvores geradoras no grafo. Por isso você já as conhecia!

O **peso** dessa árvore é a soma dos valores associados as arestas dela, nesse caso:

```
5 + 8 + 4 + 7 + 3 = 27
```

Uma árvore geradora é chamada **mínima** se, dentre todas as árvores geradoras que existem no grafo, a soma dos pesos nas arestas dela é o menor possível.

Nesse grafo, uma MST (do inglês, *minimum spanning tree*) pode ser:

[image: mst]

O peso dessa é:

```
1 + 3 + 3 + 4 + 8 == 19
```

Dois algoritmos famosos para encontrar uma MST são o de [**Prim**](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Prim) e o de [Kruskal](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Kruskal).

Assim como quase tudo legal em grafos, MSTs tem várias aplicações. Você pode dar uma olhada [aqui](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree#Applications) (infelizmente, em inglês, não achei uma boa pagina em português).

Mas como exemplo de algum uso, imagine que nós temos cidades que precisam ser ligadas por estradas (um clássico, não?). Se quisermos construir o número mínimo de estradas que ligue todas as cidades e que, também, tenham o menor custo. A solução é uma MST! Ou você pode brincar de fazer [probleminha da OBI](http://br.spoj.com/problems/COPA14/) :P.

Comment: +1 muito boa a resposta :)

Comment: Por que na arvore de expansão mínima, foi conectado o nó E com o C (valendo 8) sendo que poderia ser feito uma conexão entre D com C valendo 4? Assim o peso total seria de 15?