# Como eu acho menor ciclo de um grafo não dirigido?

Tags: grafo

Eu consigo achar um ciclo em um grafo não dirigido. Mas eu não consigo pensar em um jeito de listar os vértices de cada ciclo, e nem achar o menor ciclo. Como eu faço isso?

Comment: Já fez alguma coisa? Pode especificar melhor sua duvida, o que você está tentando?

Comment: Estou tentando acabar o algoritmo para verificar se existe um ciclo no grafo. Eu queria listar todos os ciclos de um grafo não dirigido. E queria achar o menor ciclo desse grafo.

Comment: Posso te indicar onde procurar, o livro fundamentos matemáticos para ciência da computação, Judith L Gersting.

Comment: Se bem que tenho quase certeza que é um problema NP, por que o número de caminhos é fatorial se for um grafo completo.

Comment: Valeu cara, vou dar uma olhada!

Comment: É realmente um problema NP, acredito.

Comment: Olhe também este [tópico](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22245/o-que-%C3%A9-%C3%A1rvore-geradora-m%C3%ADnima), para ver se não ajuda na dúvida.

Answer (score 1):

Existem diversos algoritmos, para grafos valorados, ou seja, onde cada aresta tem um peso, exemplos: Algoritmo de Dijkstra, Algoritmo de Bellman-Ford, Algoritmo A*, Algoritmo de Floyd-Warshall, Algoritmo de Johnson.

Porém como o encontro do menor caminho é um problema NP completo, as soluções são ineficientes, ou até matematicamente incalculáveis em números nem tão grandes. Se não me engano para grafos direcionados usava o algoritmo de [Floyd-Warshall](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Floyd-Warshall).

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente você deve dar peso `1` a todas as arestas existentes de seu grafo e peso `INFINITO` às arestas `grafo[i][i]` para todo vértice `i`. Também torne seu grafo pseudo-direcionado:

```
grafo[i][j] = 1
grafo[j][i] = 1
```

para quaisquer vértices `i` e `j` que estiverem conectados.

Geralmente, o peso na aresta `grafo[i][i]` é de `0`, o que faz sentido quando você procura o *caminho mais curto*, já que não custa nada *não se mover no grafo*, mas se você mantiver dessa forma e executar os algoritmos abaixo, seu resultado final será apenas `0`, já que o menor ciclo de um vértice até si mesmo vai ser sempre o caminho **vértice `i` -> vértice `i`**, ou seja, *não se movimentar no grafo*.

Dito isso, você pode executar o [Algoritmo de Dijkstra](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Dijkstra) para todo vértice `i`, usando `i` como o vértice inicial e final do algoritmo, ou seja, **quanto custa chegar até o vértice `i` a partir do próprio vértice `i`** (lembrando que a resposta não vai ser `0` porque você definiu que `grafo[i][i] = INFINITO`). E como os pesos das arestas são todos `1`, o menor caminho lhe dará também o ciclo de menor distância. Executando esse algoritmo para todos os vértices você terá que `grafo[i][i]` vai ser o custo do menor ciclo no qual o vértice `i` está envolvido, para todo vértice `i`. Complexidade final **O(n^3)**:

```
Dijkstra: O(n^2)
Executado n vezes, onde n é a quantidade de vértices no grafo.
Final: O(n^2) * n --> O(n^3)
```

Para achar o menor ciclo no grafo inteiro, execute o algoritmo acima e depois pegue `min(grafo[i][i])` para todo vértice `i`, ou seja: pegando todos os ciclos no qual os vértices estão envolvidos, qual deles é o menor?!

E, finalmente, para listar os vértices envolvidos no menor ciclo, adicione ao algoritmo uma lista dos vértices anteriormente visitados no menor caminho (menor ciclo, nesse caso) entre quaisquer vértices `i` e `j` e retorne a lista do vértice `i` que fizer parte do menor ciclo encontrado por `min(grafo[i][i])`, como discutido acima. [exemplo <sup>en</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Pseudocode).